# "Would nothing do but thou must at once break the eternal compact?" - meaning in the context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I am utterly lost in deciphering the very last sentence from the story Haita the Shepherd:

> In the obscurity the maiden's figure grew dim and indistinct and her
> voice seemed to come from a distance, as she said, in a tone of
> sorrowful reproach: 'Presumptuous and ungrateful youth! must I then so
> soon leave thee? **Would nothing do but thou must at once break the
> eternal compact?**'

I tired hard to put together various meanings but e.g. the "eternal compact" is something I cannot understand.

Comment: _Compact_ is used in the sense of _formal agreement_. (NB Having looked up the story online, this appears not to be the 'very last' sentence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "eternal compact" is an agreement that someone understood as a promise that would not be broken.
[American Heritage Dictionary "compact"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=compact)

> An agreement or a covenant. See Synonyms at agreement.

Glossing the entire sentence,

> Would nothing do but thou must at once break the eternal compact?

> Would nothing have satisfied you except breaking the agreement that was to last forever?